# Accessing a symlink over tftp

Tags: linux, symlink, tftp, inetd

I am using `GNU` `inetd` and `tftpd` (under `cygwin`, but that shouldn't matter), and I need to have many symbolic links pointing to only a few different files, which should be accessible via `tftp`.

tftp directory looks like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 12 Jun  4 21:29 link.bin -> file.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1  6 Jun  2 01:38 file.bin
```

and tftp says this:

```
tftp> get link.bin
Error code 1: File not found
```

I used `ln -s file.bin link.bin`

Can tftpd handle symlinks? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not a programming question and is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will tftp pull the file when you try to tftp file.bin directly?

Also is tftp your only solution here?

Comment: Yes, tftp is used for network boot. Pulling file.bin directly works wthout any problems.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this link then.
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=148149

Comment: Yep, it works now. It turns out you have to use relative instead of absolute path to target, and keep it within the tftp directory scope.